# Add ALT attribute via jquery seems not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to auto assign the alt attribute to images without it. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var attr = $(this).attr('alt');
    if (typeof attr === typeof undefined || attr === false) {
        $('img').each(function () {
            var $img = $(this);
            var filename = $img.attr('src');
            $img.attr('title', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/')) + 1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
            $img.attr('alt', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/')) + 1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
        });
    }
});
```

I have a dropdown selector with flag images for countries. Until user do not click on the dropdown selector the images are not displayed. I think that this is causing the code to do not work as expected.

If I check the output of the page, for example in Firefox view source code, I can't find any alt attribute added to the images. Meanwhile if I just analize the element in Firefox I see that the alt attribute is correctly added to the img tag.

Why? What's wrong? How should I edit it so that the page always has the alt attributes added to the code soon as it loads? This is important to me for page accessibility.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you could provide your html so we can test your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").prop("alt", "This is some alt text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying images on selecting dropdown value but jquery script getting executed as soon as DOM is ready.
You need to execute your code on change of drop down, please refer below code

NOTE: assuming `YourDropDownId` is the id of dropdown element and image alter code is working. You need to put exact id of your dropdwon and if id is not present then refer to different [jquery selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to bind the change event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#YourDropDownId').on('change', function(){
        $('img').each(function () {
            var $img = $(this);
            var filename = $img.attr('src');
            var value = filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/')) + 1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
            $img.attr('title', value);
            $img.attr('alt', value);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want that the alt attribute is added even if I do not click on the dropdown. I want that the attribute is added soon as the page is generated.

Comment: to do that DOM should contain all the image element (even though images are hidden) in that case your code should work. If you are not seeing alt attribute on inspecting element then it is due to browsers limitation but you can verify it by executing `console.log($('#ImageId').attr('alt'));` in the browser console

Comment: Yes, they are hidden but it seems that the DOM contains them.

Comment: ok, then your code should work. Just user console for verification

Comment: I got this error message using console: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function at <anonymous>:1:49

Comment: Can you confirm if jquery library included properly in your page and can you reproduce this issue on jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: Too hard, I could give you a link to take a look if you want, but not in public. I could send you by email or some other way... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery("img").each(function(){
       if(!jQuery(this).attr("alt")  || jQuery(this).attr("alt") == ''){
            var filename = jQuery(this).attr('src');
            var alt = filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/')) + 1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
            jQuery(this).attr("alt", alt);
       }
   });
});
```